# Multiple registration flows and profile types with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-registration, django-users, django-allauth, django-profiles

I have **two kind of users**: the **first** has to pay in oder to register to the site and he can perform a set of actions. The **second** can register and login for free (with their Facebook or Google or Username&Password) and can perform a *different* set of actions.

Both need to have a profile and custom fields that of course will be different for user kind.

- Is it possible to implement this with *django-allauth*?
- If not would it be a good idea to use another registration app (e.g. *django-registration*) for handling the paying users and django-allauth for the social login? Would they conflict?
- A better way to do this?